# Running a .exe application from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms-designer, visual-c#-express-2010

I have an application that I run on the command prompt as follows:

```
C:\some_location> "myapplication.exe" headerfile.h
```

I want to create a Windows Forms application where the user can specify the location of the executable and also the header file so that the Windows Forms application can do this for him/her, and the user wouldn't have to go to the command line and do it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\some_location\myapplication.exe");
```

For arguments:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\some_location\myapplication.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "header.h";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Obviously you can pull these names/arguments from text boxes.

Comment: Thank you. It was of great help.

Comment: @AbhishekVedamoorthy, you should click the check mark to the left to accept this as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 7):

You can try with this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("yourExecutable.exe");

startInfo.Arguments = "header.h"; // Your arguments

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

See *[ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_UseShellExecute)*. This page will provide you with the full information about the .exe process information.

Another way that I used is:

```
ProcessStartInfo objProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(@"Yours .exe path");
objProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
objProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process.Start(objProcess);
```

And it's working fine.