# How to connect windows forms to wix bootsrapper project?

Tags: wix

If I click install button on windows form it should process the wix's msi package install in bootstrapper project. what coding should I've to mention on that windows form's button click. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please be more clear about  your question? Without enough details , its very unlikely that someone in the community will respond. What exactly are you trying to acheive? Are you trying to launch the Wix bootstrapper executable from a windows form?  Please refine your quesiton further so that  someone could respond .

Comment: yes i trying to launch wix bootstrapper executable from windows form.@Kiran Hegde

Comment: Does this help. Answered already on stackoverflow   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635856/running-a-exe-application-from-windows-forms