# C# Application to launch a Steam game

Tags: c#, launching-application

I'm new to C#.

I am thinking as a little practice project in Visual Studio i am going to make a little application that launches a game (Counter Strike: Global Offensive) when you click a button.

Just a couple of Points:

- Is this a bit too much as a first project?
- Would i need it so when you click the button it would just have to
  look for the launch.exe for that game?

Comment: I think you will find the answers to your questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635856/running-a-exe-application-from-windows-forms

Comment: What you're after is basically provided in the Start() methods provided by the Process class in the .NET framework.  Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bit too much as a first project?

Not at all. It is pretty much starting application with some command line parameters.

> Would i need it so when you click the button it would just have to
>   look for the launch.exe for that game?

Steam games are launched by `steam://` uri scheme which maps to `steam.exe` executable. So you pretty much need to start `steam.exe` process passing uri like `steam://rungameid/game_id` where `game_id` is numerical id of that game.

Comment: Is there a way to set launch options also?

Comment: Hello, what method do I pass this URL into? I don't think CreateProcess or Shellexecute are working