# Run a published console app from win form app

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, exe, publish

I have a win form application that accept exe file and folder path as    argument.

- Then a console app is launched. But in my case these console apps are
  also published.
- When I execute from Debug console app work but when I select
  Setup.exe from published app the application installs and  then
  crash. With argument out of range error.
- A [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11635884/2343086) can be seen here. But it work with unpublished
  exe which I am already doing.
- Can I get name of the installed console app something like
  "WINWORD.exe" or "Chrome.exe".

Comment: If the app takes a value as argument on startup, do you pass these to the winform after installation? Do you have any code in place that makes sure these values are passed on startup and cleanly exists if not?

Comment: I pass my parameter path to Process.StartInfo.Arguments. Which work in debug mode but not after installation